# Is there a sample MongoDB Database along the lines of world for MySql?

Tags: mongodb

As someone new to Mongo, I am looking for a sample MongoDB database that I can import and play with.
Something along the lines of [world](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html) for mysql or [Northwind](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en) for MSSQL.

Is there one? (I couldn't find any reference to one at http://www.mongodb.org nor did my googling help)

Comment: There is currently no sample database available for MongoDB. It would not surprise me to see one in the future. I know that doesn't help you now, but people are listening :)

Comment: @vinipsmaker what exactly are you looking for, your bounty description sounds like a statement rather than a question

Comment: @Sammaye: I'm looking for downloadable easy-to-import collections that I could use to play with MongoDB. But I only can give the +100 for one user, then I cited which factors can be used to rate the quality of answers.

Comment: @vinipsmaker sounds like a cause for a open source project tbh, I would do it if I had enough time

Comment: @Sammaye, maybe you have time to elaborate a guideline for anyone interested (and with spare time) in taking such a project.

Comment: @vinipsmaker I personally would build an app and then populate it with test data and then separate that test data from the app and call that the project. That method always produces the best results from my own experience. I personally use a youtube like site I made, it has a rather complex and intricate schema but it is quite simple to understand making for a decent testing and learning curve for data manipulation

Comment: http://www.valleyprogramming.com/blog/big-data-datasets-large-examples-boulder-colorado-hadoop-mongodb

Comment: [mongodb-json-files](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongodb-json-files)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For *NIX/Mac OS this can be done in two simple steps

```
wget http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json
mongoimport -v --file=zips.json
```

For Windows users:
Please follow the following steps to import from the json file if you are using windows 7:

- Download the above mentioned [JSON file](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json) and place it inside a folder (say `d:\sample`)
- Open a command prompt, start the mongo server by going in to the bin directory and typing in `mongoD`
- Now take another command prompt and go to the bin directory again and write the following command

  `C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport --db test --collection zips --file d:\sample\zips.json`
- The import should start working immediately and at the end it should show something like this :
  **Thu Dec 19 17:11:22 imported 29470 objects**

That's it!

Comment: Sample data contains 29K US cities, location and population. This is an awesome data set to experience with Mongo aggregation :)

Comment: As of MongoDB 4.4.0, mongoimport is part of [MongoDB Database Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/), a separate download.

Answer (score 58):

I found [this](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json)  you can import the json data with:

```
mongoimport --db scratch --collection zips --file zips.json
```

I guess that you can import any json data that you find, it also supports csv and tsv. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://www.json-generator.com/

Comment: getting an error though : "E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 20):

This doesn't have everything, but it is a nice step towards getting Northwind on MongoDB:

https://github.com/tmcnab/northwind-mongo

Answer (score 14):

Download the collection of Northwind csv files from  https://github.com/tmcnab/northwind-mongo/archive/master.zip

Execute following command to import csv into mongodb

```
mongoimport -d Northwind -c categories --type csv --file categories.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c customers --type csv --file customers.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c employee-territories --type csv --file employee-territories.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c employees --type csv --file employees.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c northwind --type csv --file northwind.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c order-details --type csv --file order-details.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c orders --type csv --file orders.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c products --type csv --file products.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c regions --type csv --file regions.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c shippers --type csv --file shippers.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c suppliers --type csv --file suppliers.csv --headerline
mongoimport -d Northwind -c territories --type csv --file territories.csv --headerline
```

This can be used for both Windows and Liinux OS

Answer (score 9):

After downloading [Northwind](https://github.com/tmcnab/northwind-mongo) data as per @tslater, I cleaned it up a bit..

[image]

And ran the following PowerShell command to import into the mongo:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\MongoDb\samples\northwind\csv" -Filter *.csv | `
Foreach-Object {
    C:\MongoDb\bin\mongoimport.exe -h localhost:55000 -d northwind -c $_.BaseName --type csv --file $_.FullName --headerline 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/ provides a json file at the link :  http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json    which is zip code data.

This can be used for Map-Reduce, Aggregation and Grouping queries learning purposes and the above tutorial link at MongoDB also shows how.

For Windows: You can install a MongoVUE tool (from http://www.mongovue.com) , which is IDE for MongoDB shell operations and also provides Map-Reduce, Aggregation and Filtering support as well as data import from MySQL databases to MongoDB.

The JSON file at the link above has 3 duplicate _id entries which will hinder the import process a bit and you may have to do removeall for inserted documents. But in the end you should have 29,467 documents in your collection.

[image: MongoVUE IDE after the import]

Answer (score 2):

You can create [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/) benchmark data-sets and import them.

Example import for lineitem table:

```
./mongoimport -d test -c lineitem --type csv -f  l_orderkey,l_partkey,l_suppkey,l_linenumber,l_quantity,l_extendedprice,l_discount,l_tax,l_returnflag,l_linestatus,l_shipdate,l_commitdate,l_receiptdate,l_shipinstruct,l_shipmode,l_comment --file /home/metdos/mongo/tpc-h/tpch_2_13_0/lineitem.tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

I am updating movies collection, whenever get free time.
Personally it is very useful for me as it contains embedded object, array field, string field, date field. Click here to get JSON file of [movie collection](https://github.com/mistertandon/node-express-hbs/blob/master/movies_collection.json)

Demo of one document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5692a15524de1e0ce2dfcfa3"),
    "title" : "Toy Story 4",
    "year" : 2011,
    "rated" : "G",
    "released" : ISODate("2010-06-18T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "runtime" : 206,
    "countries" : [ 
        "USA"
    ],
    "genres" : [ 
        "Animation", 
        "Adventure", 
        "Comedy"
    ],
    "director" : "Lee Unkrich",
    "writers" : [ 
        "John Lasseter", 
        "Andrew Stanton", 
        "Lee Unkrich", 
        "Michael Arndt"
    ],
    "actors" : [ 
        "Tom Hanks", 
        "Tim Allen", 
        "Joan Cusack", 
        "Ned Beatty"
    ],
    "plot" : "The toys are mistakenly delivered to a day-care center instead of the attic right before Andy leaves for college, and it's up to Woody to convince the other toys that they weren't abandoned and to return home.",
    "poster" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxOTY4Mjc0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTA4MDQyMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "imdb" : {
        "id" : "tt0435761",
        "rating" : 8.4,
        "votes" : 500084
    },
    "tomato" : {
        "meter" : 99,
        "image" : "certified",
        "rating" : 8.9,
        "reviews" : 287,
        "fresh" : 283,
        "consensus" : "Deftly blending comedy, adventure, and honest emotion, Toy Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works.",
        "userMeter" : 89,
        "userRating" : 4.3,
        "userReviews" : 602138
    },
    "metacritic" : 92,
    "awards" : {
        "wins" : 56,
        "nominations" : 86,
        "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins & 86 nominations."
    },
    "type" : "movie",
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-02-13T04:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "parvesh",
            "rating" : 8.9,
            "comment" : "My first review for Toy Story 3, hoping it will execute while trying for the very first time."
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-02-13T04:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "Prabhash",
            "rating" : 9.3,
            "comment" : "My second review for Toy Story 3, hoping it will execute while trying for the very first time."
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2017-02-11T04:00:00.000Z"),
            "name" : "praveen",
            "rating" : 6.7,
            "comment" : "My third review for Toy Story 3, hoping it will execute while trying for the very first time."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: 404  This is not the web page you are looking for.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: It's my bad, accidentally I made repository private. It's available for now. Sorry for trouble.